# Flutter: Use Icon Font From Another Package

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages, flutter-pub, flutter-font

### I developed separated UI package for my project.

Here is it's simplified structure:

```yaml
project:
│
...
│
├── lib:
│   │
│   └── classes using AppIcons.ttf:
│
└── packages:
    │
    └── ui-kit:
        │
        ├── lib:
        │   │
        │   └── classes using AppIcons.ttf:
        │
        └── assets:
            │
            └── icons:
                │
                └── AppIcons.ttf:
```

`packages/ui-kit/pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: AppIcons.ttf
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/icons/AppIcons.ttf
```

`packages/ui-kit/app_icons.dart`:

```dart
abstract class AppIcons {
  
  static const _kFontFam = 'AppIcons';

  static const IconData ic_add = IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  
   ...

}
```

### The question is - How can I use `AppIcons.ic_add` inside `lib/`

So when I tried to place icon (`Icon(AppIcons.ic_add)`) I always get **placeholder instead of my icon**

### Please tell me if it possible to use icons placed outside root package

### and how can I implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I **solved** this question.

For those who faced the same problem here is my solution:

`packages/ui-kit/app_icons.dart`:

```yaml
...

flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: AppIcons.ttf
      fonts:
        - asset: packages/ui-kit/assets/icons/AppIcons.ttf

...
```

### This solution applies to all types to assets outside root app package.